# watchOS 10 CLLocationManager problem getting user location permission

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-location, watchos

I have an iOS app with a companion watchOS app since a couple of years. Everything used to work just fine.
Now with iOS 17 and watchOS 10 there seems to be a problem when asking users for permission to use their location.
I have my `let locationManager = CLLocationManager()` and further down the road I then ask the user for it's permission to get his location by calling `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`. The problem now is that nothing happens. There is no dialog popping up, asking the user if it's fine to get his location. All other permissions i ask (HealthKit e.g.) are presented, just not the one for the location.

I of course have my correct Info.plist entry for `Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description`. Again... all of that worked just fine prior to watchOS 10.

I did some digging and found two interesting things.

1. If I turn my app into a watch-OS-ONLY app, the dialog pops up again. But I don't want that of course. I want to keep my companion app.
2. In the console app I discovered this message:

   ```
   standard    10:10:50.684329+0200    locationd   {"msg":"#AuthPrompt #Warning Delaying authorization request placed while insufficiently in-use", "ClientKeyPath":iat.<my-bundle-id>:, "requestType":0, "inUseLevel":0}
   ```

   So it's complaining that my app is `insufficiently in-use`?!?

So summary: Calling `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization` does NOT open the system dialog asking the user about the permission. Therefore the authorization status will always stay as `notDetermined`. Did anybody else experienced that problem? And is there a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am also facing same issue with my watch os app. Whenever I remove app from device and install new from test flight then I'm not getting location authentication alert in watch os 10. (It's working fine before watch os 10)

Right now I'm using following workaround. (This workaround will reset all the apps locations and privacy)

Make sure iPhone and watch is connected with Bluetooth.
Remove watch app from background.
Goto Settings app ->General->Transfer or Reset iPhone->Reset->Reset Location and Privacy.
Open watch app again then you will receive location authentication alert.

Comment: Yes, that works, but is not a real solution for real customers :(
Hopefully either apple fixes that or we can figure out what to change in oder for it to always pop up...

Comment: Yes @Georg this is not a real solutions for customers, Hopefully apple will fix this issue in next upcoming os update.

Comment: Also @Georg You can check this link https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/736785 because many developers are facing same issue.